# Double wwwroot folder when deploying blazor via devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, blazor

When I publish our blazor server app via Visual Studio to a local folder all is fine. We get a single wwwroot folder with all the css etc in it. However when deployed via Blazor to the server we get the wwwroot folder inside another wwwroot folder for some reason. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was a little curious.

Basically I had the following in the csproj file for the client project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-select.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\cust-bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\cust.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\navbar.css" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\css\site.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-select.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-select.min.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\custbootstrap.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\cust.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\navbar.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\site.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\img\navbarlogo.png" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\bootstrap-select.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\bootstrap.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\references.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\js\site.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\static\master.html" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="4.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="PSC.Blazor.Components.Tabs" Version="1.0.6" />
```

I Noticed that one of my other Blazor projects did not have these in. I removed the wwwroot entries from this file and it fixed the double folder issue.

I have no idea how they got into the project file in the first place...